# In Moq, is there a simple way to make Setup() return null, regardless of all arguments supplied?

Tags: unit-testing, null, installation, moq

Using Moq, I want to Setup() a call, so that it always returns null, regardless of any supplied parameters.

I do it like this:

```
_myMock.Setup(mock => mock.MyMethod(
  It.IsAny<int?>(), 
  It.IsAny<String>(), 
  It.IsAny<String>(), 
  It.IsAny<String>())).
  Returns((IList<Item>)null
);
```

Quite lenghty for just returning null. **Can I make it simpler?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't make the setup, with the default MockBehavior.Loose it will return default values - null for classes, 0 for numbers, the default value for structs.

Caveat: if the return type is IEnumerable or Array, it will return and empty set, not null. In that case, you need an explicit setup.

It's very strange that it does not return empty IList though, as IList is IEnumerable. Probably it's a bug, but anyway, works for what you asked for :)

Both these examples work (using also FluentAssertions and NUnit, besides Moq):

```
    public interface ISomeDummy
    {
        IList<int> Nums(int i);
    }

    [Test]
    public void NullSetupTestWithMockOf()
    {
        var mock = Mock.Of<ISomeDummy>();

        var items = mock.Nums(1);
        items.Should().BeNull();
    }

    [Test]
    public void NullSetupTestWithoutSetup()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ISomeDummy>();

        var items = mock.Object.Nums(1);
        items.Should().BeNull();
    }
```

Comment: Works wonderfully. Thanks @Sunnry Milenov. I added a note about your code.

Comment: Actually it was https://sharptestex.codeplex.com/, not FluentAssertions, and the syntax was correct, but anyway :)

Comment: I'm sorry. Thanks for letting me know about sharptestex though.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Your method requires four parameters, so you gotta supply them.

Comment: The downvoter is encouraged to leave a comment. While this answer is short, it is still correct.